# Creating Google Contact using JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, nsxmlparser, google-contacts-api

I am creating contact using Google API.

[This official link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=en#creating_contacts) uses XML, is there any way to use JSON instead of XML ?

I am using PHP.

Comment: I think the only way to use json instead of xml in an api which takes xml is to convert json to xml.

Comment: @Alex in output we can get the json as output from gmail api

Comment: I just don't see any json on the page you mentioned. Here (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference) you can find detailed description of google contacts api. And here is the first passage from there: "This document provides detailed reference documentation for the raw protocol (XML and HTTP) for the Google Contacts Data API".

Comment: And they just say about json once - describing response formats: "The type of feed to return, such as atom (the default), rss, or json".

Comment: yes json as response

Comment: Well, if you want to get response in json look at this paragraph: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#contacts-query-parameters-reference